# Removing the email validation requirement

Tags: 6, users

I'm building a premium membership site where a visitor can purchase a role, and gain access to the privileged content using the Ubercart module. I've got all that working fine, but the last tiny snag that my client wants to remove is to remove the validation email requirement that's fired when someone signs up on the site in Login Toboggan (6.1.9). I've got nothing set that is forcing this extra step and I've come to believe that this may be a feature in Drupal (Acquia distro 6.22) core for any user that registers. I was hoping that this module (Logintoboggan) would eliminate that step but I've not as of yet been able to do so.

I can allow the newly registered user access by setting that in the module, but the notification and validation email requirement still remains. Can anyone recommend a way around this? I just want them to be able to come to the site purchase their membership without any validation/confirmation email. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That setting is part of core Drupal.

Go to admin/user/settings, and under 'User Registration Settings' set 'Public registrations' to 'Visitors can create accounts and no administrator approval is required'. Also untick the 'Require e-mail verification when a visitor creates an account' checkbox and you should be good to go.

[image: screenshot]

Once you've done that it might be worth re-checking your Login Toboggan settings just to make sure there's nothing interfering with your new settings.

Comment: Thanks for the response - I've actually got those settings in place already and I've poured over my login toboggan settings too looking for something, but I can't find anything. In order to join the site they must also become a user and I've got that part, but the thing that's happening is that Drupal is firing this verification/registration confirmation email (even after I've turned off everything I could find that would require it) and I can't find the source of it. I'm trying to create a similar checkout process that the lullabots have on their drupalize.me site - simple and effective.

Comment: @RobOrr Once the settings are the ones reported here, Drupal should not send any verification email. If that happens, it is not something caused by Drupal; probably there is a module that is causing that.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to inject your own logic using either [hook_user()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!core.php/function/hook_user/6) to set an email which will validate, or perhaps use [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!core.php/function/hook_form_alter/6) to adjust the values submitted during registration.

I've had to do the former for a site where we imported a large user DB with some blank and some duplicate emails; we checked for emails which would trigger errors, and replaced them with emails of the form UID@internal.example.org, which are valid but not deliverable. It was some years ago - apologies for not recalling the exact details!

The exact details of how you'd do this will depend on your site setup. For example: do you want to bypass validation in order to permit non-standard emails, or blank emails, or what? As Drupal expects emails to be unique per account, you may need to look out for what happens if you permit, say, blank emails.